# 1c-Битрикс. Проблема с автоподгрузкой товара в интернет-магазине.

Tags: 1с, битрикс, jquery, jquery-tools

Есть интернет-магазин на 1с-Битрикс. Есть разделы. В каждом разделе первоначально выведено по 30 элементов. При прокрутке страницы остальные товары подгружаются автоматически. Но есть раздел, который просто не хочет подгружать товары остальные.  FireBug выдает ошибку.  http://myscreenshot.info/i/0003/585851395213755140926409227353.png. Причем в других разделах такой ошибки не наблюдается.
Сделал следующее:
1) Создал еще раздел тестовый;
2) Скопировал исходники из другого работающего раздела.
При переходе на вновь созданный раздел, появляется ошибка, описанная выше.
Раздел пробовал создавать и через админку и через FTP. Не помогло.

Может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: по первой ссылке недоступен скриншот. Вот здесь доступно https://monosnap.com/image/fP7PX9CzizZSqMCeQg6bozod6LJmy2

Comment: @Slavajax, проверьте, не написали ли вы  

    $(#id)

вместо  

    $('#id')

Кроме того, проверьте, не используете ли вы такую конструкцию:  

    $("[attribute=#]"); /* Неправильно */
    $("[attribute='#']"); /* Правильно */
    $("[attribute=\\#]"); /* Правильно */

Все символы из списка:  

    !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^{|}~`

Нужно экранировать двойным обратным слэшем.

Comment: спасибо проверю. Вообще эта ошибка появилась после обновления битрикса как выяснилось.